# Grails 3 : overriding service in doWithSpring

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails3, grails3.2.0

In grails 2, overriding a bean in a XPlugin.groovy just required to redefine the service in the doWithSpring() method:

```
def doWithSpring = {
    tokenStorageService(TokenStorageProxyService) { it.autowire = 'byName' }
}
```

I started programming in Grails 3, already having an experience with Grails 2 and tried the same kind of overriding in a new plugin, as I'm creating a Grails 3 version of some of my existing Grails 2 plugins:

```
Closure doWithSpring() { {->
    tokenStorageService(TokenStorageProxyService) {
        it.autowire = 'byName'
    }
} }
```

I made some integration tests:

```
@Integration
class SecurityServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    SecurityService securityService
    TokenStorageProxyService tokenStorageService
...
}
```

When running the tests, I get the error:

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.JwtTokenStorageService' to required type 'com.b2boost.grails3.auth.client.TokenStorageProxyService' for property 'tokenStorageService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.JwtTokenStorageService' to required type 'com.b2boost.grails3.auth.client.TokenStorageProxyService' for property 'tokenStorageService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
> at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:605)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:400)
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
> at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
> ...
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.JwtTokenStorageService' to required type 'com.b2boost.grails3.auth.client.TokenStorageProxyService' for property 'tokenStorageService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found 
> at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
> at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
> ... 37 more
> ```

It seems that the default JwtTokenStorageService has not been overrided by my TokenStorageProxyService, resulting in a ConversionNotSupportedException when the service is wired into the integration test. How can I override the service in my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems that my custom module was loaded after Spring security rest. The tokenStorageService from SSR thus overrided my service while the converse should have happened:

> Configuring MyModule...
>
> ... finished configuring MyModule
>
> Configuring Spring Security Core ...
>
> ... finished configuring Spring Security Core
>
> Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
>
> ... finished configuring Spring Security REST

Adding the following line in the MyModuleGrailsPlugin.groovy ensured the modules loaded in the right order:

```
def loadAfter = [
    'springSecurityRest'
]
```